# Can't establish HTTPS connections on some Windows XP/Server 2003 machines

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

We have problems with our application on some machines running Windows XP and Windows Server 2003. The application crashes upon trying to connect to our webservice via HTTPS. The event viewer shows the following after the crash:

```
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CAPISafe.CertGetCertificateChain(IntPtr, System.Security.Cryptography.SafeCertContextHandle, System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ByRef, System.Security.Cryptography.SafeCertStoreHandle, CERT_CHAIN_PARA ByRef, UInt32, IntPtr, System.Security.Cryptography.SafeCertChainHandle ByRef)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain.BuildChain(IntPtr, System.Security.Cryptography.SafeCertContextHandle, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection, System.Security.Cryptography.OidCollection, System.Security.Cryptography.OidCollection, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationMode, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationFlag, System.DateTime, System.TimeSpan, System.Security.Cryptography.SafeCertChainHandle ByRef)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain.Build(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.VerifyRemoteCertificate(System.Net.Security.RemoteCertValidationCallback)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CompleteHandshake()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(System.Net.Security.ProtocolToken, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[], Int32, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[], Int32, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[], Int32, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[], System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(System.Net.Security.ProtocolToken, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[], Int32, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[], Int32, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[], Int32, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[], System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(System.Net.Security.ProtocolToken, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[], Int32, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[], Int32, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[], Int32, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[], System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(System.Net.Security.ProtocolToken, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[], Int32, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[], Int32, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[], Int32, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[], System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(System.Net.Security.ProtocolToken, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[], Int32, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[], Int32, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[], Int32, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[], System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(System.Net.Security.ProtocolToken, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[], Int32, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean, Byte[], System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(System.Net.LazyAsyncResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(System.Net.LazyAsyncResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndSubmitRequest()
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckDeferredCallDone(System.Net.ConnectStream)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(System.Net.WebRequest)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(System.Net.WebRequest)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(System.String, System.Object[])
   at {METHOD THAT CALLS WEBSERVICE}
```

The webservice communication is handled by a service reference. It does not matter which webservice we try to call. The error even happens when we are using a totally different server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just solved the problem. It seems like this problem only happens when the machine building the application has Visual Studio 2013 installed.

EDIT: This was a false assumption. We are using libcef in our application and this seems to be the root cause for the problem. The version that was built on the machine without VS2013 contained a wrong version of libcef. If that happens the application will continue without the CEF functionality, so we assumed that it was working.

Comment: We're you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: @bradmo Unfortunately not. We switched to an older version of CEF for the time being. The issue does not occur on the 2062 branch. I were able to work around the issue by opening a CEF browser instance and loading a page before making any requests in the application. But that seemed like a hacky solution.